# Uniquely identify groups of game scores that are tied

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a set that has the columns TeamId, GameId, IsWin, and IsLoss. I want to write a query that not only sums up the wins and losses for each team, but I also want to create a column that uniquely identifies the *groups* of teams that have the same number of wins and losses. In other words, if a team has the same number of wins and losses as one **or more** other teams, then they should all share the same "TieGroup"

For example, if I summed up the wins and losses, sorting by `Wins DESC, Losses ASC` and got this result:

```
Team  W L
Team1 4 0
Team2 4 0
Team3 3 1
Team4 1 3
Team5 0 4
Team6 0 4
```

Then after I add the column to group the tied teams, I would expect this result

```
Team  W L TieGroup
Team1 4 0 1
Team2 4 0 1
Team3 3 1 2
Team4 1 3 3
Team5 0 4 4
Team6 0 4 4
```

Team1 and Team2 are tied, so are in the same group. Team3 and Team4 have records that are unlike any other team so they each get their own group. Team5 and Team6 are also tied so they are in the same group.

How can I do this? I tried using `row_count()` and `rank()`, but I'm not getting the results I want.

Comment: next time try to provide something like 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can give  you faster answer

Comment: How about [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)?

Comment: I think rank() do the job what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza, I didn't know SqlFiddle existed. Will definitely use that next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using DENSE_RANK()

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/999be/8)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(team NVARCHAR(100), win INT, lose INT);

INSERT INTO tab(team, win, lose)
VALUES ('Team1', 4, 0), ('Team2', 4, 0), ('Team3', 3, 1), 
       ('Team4', 1, 3), ('Team5', 0, 4), ('Team6', 0, 4); 

SELECT 
   team
  ,win
  ,lose
  ,[tie_group] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY win DESC, lose ASC)
FROM tab;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried DENSE_RANK(), but I was putting the wins and losses in `Partition By` and that was what was messing it up. I didn't think to leave that off. Here's a version of your SqlFiddle that does the summing too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1fa5/2/0